# How to manage the asynchrounous nature of useState hook when setting a value and using it directly after

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React and can't really understand how to use the useState hook correctly.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("noname");

  const updateAndLogName = () => {
    setName("Alex");
    console.log(name); // first time => "noname"
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => updateAndLogName()}>
        Click me to change and log name in console
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-engelbart-zd7d8)

I call a method that updates the value and uses the updated value directly after. But since the setName function is asynchronous I get the original value in the console.log and have to wait until React has updated the value to get the correct result.

In this simplified example I could just take the value as a function argument and use it in both the setName and console.log, and maybe that's the way it should be done, but are there any other preferred way to handle this situation?

EDIT:

Here is another example:

[CodeSandbox 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-sea-ubypv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this simplified example I could just take the value as a function
>   argument and use it in both the setName and console.log, and maybe
>   that's the way it should be done

That is one way if you don't want to wait for another render. If waiting for a render is okay, another way could be:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  console.log("Will get here anytime name changes", name);
}, [name])
```

Also [related](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14174#issue-379211041).

Comment: Thank you! But I don't necessarily want to perform the same action every time it updates though... I updated my post with another example (don't know if adds much to the question...)

Comment: This is actually the recommended way using hooks. You can find a simple codesandbox using this approach here: https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-water-keigu . In react class components, you used to be able to use a callback function in setState that was fired whenever the state manipulation finished. When you try the same thing in hooks, you get this error message: `Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect()`

Comment: @mottosson maybe you can find some info on that in github link of my answer it seems related.